# Retornar valor de parámetro de una clase superior a otra

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo lo siguiente:

Tres capas:
Acceso a datos o persistencia
Negocio
Vista

**Edición con mas contexto:**
Quiero llenar un dgv mediante el objeto que seleccione el usuario en un combobox, en el combobox en el evento "**SelectedIndexChanged**" agregue el código para que llame a mi método en la capa de negocio, para que este llame al método de la capa de acceso a datos.
En la base de datos tengo un sp, que espera recibir el parámetro IdAplicacion

**Pero no se como hacerlo, estoy trabajando en C# WindowsForm y con SQLServer.**

Aquí el código completo con las modificaciones sugeridas:

**Método en la clase de Acceso a Datos:**

```
public class CDAO_Activities
{
    private CDAO_Conexion conexion = new CDAO_Conexion();

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    
    //Muestra todas las actividades de las tres tablas relacionadas, para llenar el dgv.
    public DataTable showListActivities(int Idaplication)
    {
        
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = conexion.OpenConexion();
            command.CommandText = "ShowListActivities";
            var name = new SqlParameter("@IdAplicacion", Idaplication);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@IdAplicacion", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters["@IdAplicacion"].Value = Idaplication;
            using (SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader())

            {
                if (read.HasRows)
                {
                    table.Load(read);
                }
                conexion.CloseConexion();
                return table;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class CDAO_Applications
{
    private CDAO_Conexion conexion = new CDAO_Conexion();

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

    //Muestra los nombres de las aplicaciones, para cargarlos en el combobox
    public DataTable showListName()
    {
        command.Connection = conexion.OpenConexion();
        command.CommandText = "ListActivities";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        using (SqlDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (read.HasRows)
            {
                table.Load(read);
            }
            conexion.CloseConexion();
            return table;
        }
```

Métodos en la capa de negocios:

Para el llenado del dgv

```
public class CBO_Activities
{
    private CDAO_Activities objectCD = new CDAO_Activities();
    //Llenar dgv
    public DataTable listActivities(int IdcmbApp)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table = objectCD.showListActivities(IdcmbApp);
        return table;

    }
}
```

Para la carga de datos en el ComboBox:

```
public class CBO_Applications
{
    private CDAO_Applications objectCD = new CDAO_Applications();

    //Listar nombres en el combobox
    public DataTable listName()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table = objectCD.showListName();
        return table;

    }
```

Vista, llamado de los métodos anteriores:

```
public partial class frmActivities : Form
{
    CBO_Activities objectCD = new CBO_Activities();
    CBO_Applications objectCDN = new CBO_Applications();

    public frmActivities()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listaNom();
        cmbApp.SelectedItem = null;

    }

    private void frmActivities_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        listaMod();
    }

   

    private void listaNom()
    {
        cmbApp.DataSource = objectCDN.listName();
        cmbApp.DisplayMember = "aplication";
        cmbApp.ValueMember = "Idaplication";//Id a enviar al sp de Sql y al metodo que invoca el sp

    }

    private void listaMod()
    {

            dataGridView1.DataSource = objectCD.listActivities(cmbApp.SelectedIndex);
    }

    private void cmbApp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            if (cmbApp.SelectedIndex != 0)               
                listaMod();
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No se pudo cargar el dgv: " + error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco de antemano cualquier aporte.

Saludos

DS

Comment: Tienes que poner las clases publicas, ademas tambien tienes que poner variables que se igualen a los parametros que quieres mandar, y necesitas poner el codigo que estas usando para darte una mejor referencia de lo que preguntas

Comment: Edite la pregunta y agregue los métodos que tengo.
@Macx

Comment: De que forma se conecta tu vista a tu controlador? Como estas enviando dicho parametro desde el front?

Comment: Mediante el instancimiento de capas una capa se comunica con otra:
Vista a Negocio
Negocio a Persistencia o acceso a datos.
O a que te refieres? @PauloUrbanoRivera

Comment: Me refiero a que desde tu vista estas enviando los parametros de alguna manera... Estas utilizando razor? Ajax? Angular?

Comment: C# Aplicación de escritorio (No web)
Creo no lo especifique en la pregunta.@PauloUrbanoRivera

Answer (score 4):

Un par de sugerencias:

1. No está del todo claro qué es lo que preguntas. Para llenar un `DataGridView`a partir de un cambio en un `ComboBox`, no es necesaria una capa de acceso a datos. Sin embargo, si al cambiar el objeto seleccionado del ComboBox, traerás de la base de datos información relacionada con ese índice, para llenar el `DataGridView`, es otra historia. Responderé a tu pregunta más adelante basado en esa premisa.
2. No temas utilizar **más letras** al nombrar tus métodos. Es más, se recomienda que sean lo más descriptivos posibles. Por ejemplo: `objectCD.listAct()` no me dice mucho, de buenas a primeras. Podríamos inferir que significa "Lista Actualizada", pero no es expresiva en sí misma. `shAct()` agradecería un makeover, también.

Uno de los principales objetivos de la arquitectura **N-Capas** es respetar el **principio de responsabilidad única (Single Responsibility Principle)**, el primero de los principios **SOLID**. De esta manera, generalmente, tenemos una capa que se encarga de la presentación (**Front End/Presentation Layer**), Lógica de Negocios (**Business Logic**) y Acceso a Datos (**Data Access**).

Cada capa tiene, idealmente, **una única responsabilidad,** y es **recibir** el mensaje (objeto), **procesarlo** y **pasárselo** a la capa siguiente, o devolverla a quien llama si es necesario.

## Para responder tu pregunta:

Cuando se cambia la selección en el `DropDown/ComboBox`y disparas el evento `cmbAct_SelectedIndexChanged` se ejecuta el método `shAct()`. No veo cómo este método esté comunicando a la capa de lógica de negocios que hubo un cambio. El siguiente código es un ejemplo, está reducido únicamente a lo importante, pero debería ser suficiente para indicarte el camino:

### En la capa de presentación:

```
private void cmbActualizacion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var logicaNegocio = new CapaLogicaNegocio();
        try
          {
            if (cmbActualizacion.SelectedIndex != 0){               
                var dataSource = logicaNegocios.ActualizarGrid(cmbActualizacion.SelectedIndex);
          dgv.DataSource = dataSource;
}
          }
        catch(Exception error)
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al cargar dgv: " + error.Message);
          }
    }
```

### En la capa de Lógica de Negocios:

```
public class CapaLogicaNegocio {
     // ...
     public DataTable ObtenerObjetosPorIdForaneo(int idCmbActualizacion){
           // ...
           var accesoDatos = new CapaAccesoDatos();
           var dt= accesoDatos.getActi(idCmbActualizacion); // Sugiero un cambio de nombre
           return dt; // Vuelve a la capa de Presentacion
     }
}
```

### Y tu acceso a datos queda casi igual

```
public class CapaAccesoDatos {
         public DataTable getActi(int Idaplication) { // idAplication recibe idCmbActualizacion
//....
            return tbl; // a la capa de Lógica de Negocios
 }
```

De esta forma, el índice que cambió en el ComboBox baja desde la capa de presentación, llega a la capa de lógica de negocio, es recibida por la capa de acceso a datos, es procesada, la lista es obtenida, y el objeto de respuesta recorre todo el camino de vuelta hasta la capa de presentación para que ahí hagas el binding

```
dgv.DataSource = dataSource;
```

Espero te sea de utilidad. Recomiendo leer acerca de los [SOLID Principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Comment: Edite la pregunta agregando mas contexto y todo el código del programa.
Tal cual lo tengo, hice un ligero ajuste a el codigo que tengo con lo que me sugeriste ahora me filta el dgv, pero solo cuando selecciono un objeto que internamente tiene el IdAplication = 1, si selecciono otro Id 2,34, simplemente no hace el filtro. Cual puede ser el problema, no recibo ningún error. @Arriel

Comment: Cuando haces debugg y se dispara nuevamente el evento de cambio de Index, va ahí el nuevo número?

Comment: Si, el combo box tiene su propio Datasource llama al sp y entonces con cada cambio que haga toma el nuevo Id.@Arriel

Comment: Ok, entonces, deberás checar dos cosas: 1- Que ese index es el que se envía al SP en tu capa de acceso a datos. 2- Que tu SP está correcto, es decir, intenta ejecutarlo con Id 2, 34, u otro, como exponías en tu comentario.

Comment: Como valido esto?
1- Que ese index es el que se envía al SP en tu capa de acceso a datos
Lo segundo el sp ya lo he ejecutado en SQL y si me retorna los datos.
@Arriel

Comment: Pon un punto de interrupción en la línea  `var name = new SqlParameter("@IdAplicacion", Idaplication);` para asegurarte que el index correcto va en IdAplication. También pon otro en `return table` para ver qué datos vienen en el dataset

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111425/discussion-between-jose-daniel-solis-and-arriel).